# Apps Script Trigger Fails to Get Current Date

Tags: date, google-apps-script, triggers

I have created an `Apps Script` to compile data and save the results to a new `Google Sheet`.

The code gets the current date with `new Date()` and uses that for the query and to name the new sheet it creates.

Here is the relevant part of the code:

```
function exportPayroll(setDate){
  var date = new Date();
  var newWeek = Utilities.formatDate(_getSunday(date),"GMT", "MM/dd/yyyy");
  for (var company in companies){
    getPayroll(companies[company],newWeek);
  }
}
function _getSunday(d) {
  d = new Date(d);
  var day = d.getDay(),
      diff = d.getDate() - day + (day == 0 ? -7:0); // adjust when day is sunday
  return new Date(d.setDate(diff));
}
```

If I run `exportPayroll` manually, I get the exact results that I expect. So, I setup this trigger to automate the process:

[image]

When the trigger runs, the date value is `12/31/1969` instead of today.

Why does it act different with the trigger? Checking the execution transcript, I don't see any error messages.

Is there a better way to get today's date via a trigger?

Comment: When `_getSunday(d)` is run, `d` is already a date.  You don't need to create a new date object from something that is already a date object.  If the function `_getSunday(d)` is being called from multiple places, and sometimes `d` is not a date, then you need to test `d` for whether it's an object or not.  `if (typeof d !== 'object') {d = new Date(d)}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you just wan't to get the Date of the previous sunday.  Try running it this way.

```
function getLastSunday() {
  var d = new Date();
  var day = d.getDay();
  var diff = d.getDate() - day + (day == 0 ? -7:0); // adjust when day is sunday
  return new Date(d.setDate(diff));
}

function exportPayroll(){
  var newWeek = Utilities.formatDate(getLastSunday(),"GMT", "MM/dd/yyyy");
  for (var company in companies){
    getPayroll(companies[company],newWeek);
  }
}
```

Comment: This appears to work. But, what is different? Why can't I get the date in `exportPayroll` and pass it to `getLastSunday`?